# Store the return values of member function in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opencv

I am working on OpenCV Samples. I am not sure how to put the size (width * height) of many rectangles (obtained by calling the member function "size" of class Rect in a loop) in an array.

I am planning to assign the size of rectangles to an array using pointers.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You mean, like `arr[i] = size(...);` ?

Comment: Why not put  the rectangles themselves or pointers to the rectangle in the array?   A rectangle is just position,  width,  and height  with corresponding methods.  There should be no reason invent yet another storage mechanism for the height and width.

Comment: Also consider using a vector (std::vector) rather than an array unless you know exactly how many rectangles you will be dealing with and that number never changes.

Comment: @DaleWilson ... in which case `std::array` should be used.

Comment: @DaleWilson : I know the exact number of rectangles. I want to create 2 arrays(arr1 , arr2: each containing a set of rectangles) and compare one rectangle from arr1 with the whole set of arr2. I basically want to see if I have some matching rectangles with respect to size.

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah.. I have var.size() returning the size of the rectangle. var being of type Rect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good [talk](http://www.codestrokes.com/2013/11/sean-parent-no-raw-loops/) why you should try to use algorithms instead of loops.

If you have a Container with the Rects you can use `std::transform`. If your container is called `rects` and you want to store in in the array sizes, this would be used as

```
std::transform(rects.begin(), rects.end(), array, [](const Rect &rect) {
  return rect.size().area();
});
```

To find a rectangle of a particular size (named `requested_size`) you could use

```
std::find_if(rects.begin(), rects.end(), [requested_size](const Rect &rect) {
  return requested_size==rect.size().area();
});
```